# Why does jquery disable my <a href>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My website is working fine, except for my `<a href="...">` links.
They work when I don't have a jQuery function in there. When I do have the jQuery function they don't work.

My code:

```
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  body {
    font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .hidden {
    display: none;
  }

  .background-wrap {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }

  #video-bg-elem {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    background-size: 100%
  }

  .content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 1000;
  }

  .content h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 65px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #fff;
    padding-top: 18%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  .content p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    color: #aaa;
  }

  .box {
    width: 200px;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s;
    background: #e3e3e3;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .box:hover {
    background: #333;
    color: #e3e3e3
  }

  nav > ul > li {
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 1em;
  }

  nav > ul > li.active {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }

  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <br>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="producten.html">Assortiment<a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="background-wrap">
    <video id="video-bg-elem" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted">
      <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Video not supported
    </video>
  </div>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hidden').fadeIn('slow').removeclass('.hidden')
  });
  </script>
  <center>
    <div class="hidden">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>OortjesShop.nl</h1>
        <p id="test">De webwinkel voor al jouw oortjes en koptelefoons!</p>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="box"><a href="producten.html" style="text-decoration: none; color: inherit;">Bekijk ons assortiment</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

The weird thing is that my `<a href="...">` on the box does work, but the one on my menu doesn't.

When I remove the jQuery function it does work.

Comment: I see a single `<a href="#">` in your example

Comment: Sorry that's not what I mean, just each <a href="whateveritlinksto"> in my navbar doesn't work, while the one in my box does work

Comment: @LarsBeute jquery isn't to blame

Comment: did you put `<!DOCTYPE html>` at begin of file?

Comment: Doesn't the `active` class permit you from clicking it? It is in fact active when using bootstrap I believe so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your style for h1 is overlapping the navigation,just put it in your css then see the changes.

`nav {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
}`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you got a typo in the second link of your menu:

```
<a href="producten.html">Assortiment<a>
```

youre not closing it with `</a>`

AND

as [@Timbal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41511811/1644937) stated

your `h1` is overlapping your `nav`, just put to your `nav` an higher `z-index` than `z-index` of `h1`:

```
nav {    
    position: relative;    
    z-index: 1001;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `.content` is positioned absolutely so it's likely covering up your navigation bar which does not allow anything to be clicked (even if it doesn't appear to be covered).

```
.content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

When jQuery isn't included, that content is hidden which would explain why it works then. Perhaps adjust/remove that style to see if the issue persists.

Answer (score 1):

Your "content" block is z-indexed, but your menu is not. So, when your jQuery fires and reveals the content, it ends up z-indexed over the top of your menu. You have two choices. Either add:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

..to your content background so that you can click through the layer (though this may impact click events within that container), or you need to give your menu a position:absolute and a z-index higher than your "content" div.